# Powershell Parameters not working as expected in a path

Tags: powershell

In the below powershell script I am passing three string parameters.  The $ComputerName parameter line works as expected.  I am able to remote into the machine that I specify.

**Issue 1**
On the line $latestbuildfolder I am using $builddefinition parameter to specify build definition.  It appends the name of the builddefinition but does not list folder inside that folder.  If I replace $BuildDefinition parameter by "TeamBuild" our build definition name then it is able to list all the folders and get the latest folder.  Some how I feel the join is not working.  I have tried using Join-Path too and still not working.

**Issue 2**
On the line $deploycmdlocation when I try to specify $Configuration in that string it is not working.  It outputs a blank between that path.  I checked using Write-Host and the parameters is passed to the script.

```
param(
[System.String] $ComputerName,
[System.String] $Configuration,
[System.String] $BuildDefinition
)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName 
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
$latestbuildfolder = Get-ChildItem "C:\procmon\procmonBuilds\$BuildDefinition" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | SELECT-Object -First 1
$deploycmdlocation = "\procmon\procmonWebProject\$Configuration\_PublishedWebsites\procmonWebProject_Package\procmonWebProject.zip"
$finalstring = $latestbuildfolder.FullName + $deploycmdlocation
$finalstring
}
Remove-PSSession $session
```

I have tried lots of options and still no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me just felt like Inception movie.  It turns out that I have to declare param at two places.  Thanks to my co-worker friend for this solution.

Here is the final script that works for me. This is a script that runs on build machine and then does a new-pssession on remote computer get web packages from latest build drops folder.  Those parameters are passed through process template activity Invoke-Process used to invoke powershell scripts.

```
param(
[System.String] $ComputerName,
[System.String] $Config,
[System.String] $BuildDef
)
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName 
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
param(
[string] $ComputerName,
[string] $Configuration,
[string] $BuildDefinition
$latestbuildfolder = Get-ChildItem "C:\procmon\procmonBuilds\$BuildDefinition" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | SELECT-Object -First 1
$deploycmdlocation = "\procmon\procmonWebProject\$Configuration\_PublishedWebsites\procmonWebProject_Package\procmonWebProject.zip"
$finalstring = $latestbuildfolder.FullName + $deploycmdlocation
$finalstring
} -args $ComputerName, $Config, $BuildDef
Remove-PSSession $session
```

Answer (score 0):

try change like this:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { param($a, $b)
$latestbuildfolder = Get-ChildItem "C:\procmon\procmonBuilds\$b" | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | SELECT-Object -First 1 
$deploycmdlocation = "\procmon\procmonWebProject\$a\_PublishedWebsites\procmonWebProject_Package\procmonWebProject.zip"
$finalstring = $latestbuildfolder.FullName + $deploycmdlocation 
$finalstring
} -argumentlist $Configuration, $BuildDefinition
```

Comment: No Change same result.  It appends $a but doesn't list Get-Childitem and $b is always blank even though it is accessible inside the script.

Comment: @Mitul Sorry, try now. I passed worng variable.

Comment: That's Ok I corrected before trying it but same thing.  I think there is some issue with Parameters passed like this inside Path.

Comment: @Mitul I simulate locally your invoke-command and no issue passing paramenter (variable) for build a path. I can't test in a remote session but I think it can works.

Comment: Right the second line $b one works till joining but does not list folders below it.  If I replace the $b by "TeamBuild" (hard code it) then it will list my latest build folder beneath it.  And $Deploycmdlocation line has $a as blank.  so it is like procmonwebproject\\_publishedwebsites\.  If I do write-host $a it shows me "Release" so no issues in passing parameters.  They aren't giving me the output I need.  Same if I hard code "release" it will work.

Comment: Can't help more... I've just test it with remote session and simulating your path. It works for me.

Comment: not a problem.  I can't demo live either. Or may be I did a poor job explaining my issue.  I will keep trying. Thanks for help though.

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a similar issue to this the other day...try the following line...

```
$latestbuildfolder = Get-ChildItem "C:\procmon\procmonBuilds\$($b)" | ...
```

[Add a $() around your $b variable in the string and see if that helps.]

Comment: Sorry not working same result. Get-childitem command doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, try this.  Before your Invoke-Command line, try this:

$testLine = "-c:\procmon\procmonbuilds\$buildDefinition-";$testLine

See if this shows you any spaces before the final '-' as there may be some artifact that you can't see in the variable.

Comment: I also just set this up on a test environment and used Christian's example and it also worked for me with passing the parameters into the scriptblock using the -argumentlist parameter.

Comment: When I ran $testline it gave me following output -C:\procmon\procmonbuilds\- it didn't out any $builddefinition parameter.